# FragmentStatePagerAdapter Duplicate fragment

Tags: android

I'm using nested FragmentStatePagerAdapter on my single activity application. The current layout is:

```
Activitiy
  - Login Fragment
  - Master Fragment
      - Tab Fragment #1
      - Tab Fragment #2
      - Tab Fragment #3
  - Another Fragment
  - Another Fragment
```

Everytime i switch back from "Another Fragment" into "Master Fragment" the FragmentStatePagerAdapter instante the same item twice for example

First Time: Tab Fragment #1 #2 #3
Second Time: Tab Fragment #1 #1 #2 #2 #3 #3
Third Time: Tab Fragment #1 #1 #1 #2 #2 #2 #3 #3 #3.

To move from fragment to fragment i use

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, XXXX.newInstance(query), TAG_XXX)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

The MasterFragment code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initFragmentAdapter();
}

private void initFragmentAdapter() {
    final FragmentSimpleAdapter adapter = new FragmentSimpleAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(
            getString(...),
            "...",
            XXX.class);
    ...

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    PagerSlidingTabStrip viewTabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) getActivity().findViewById(
            android.R.id.tabhost);
    viewTabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    viewTabs.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
}
    private final class FragmentSimpleAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
       implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final List<String> mTitles = new LinkedList<>();
    private final List<String> mInstances = new LinkedList<>();
    private final List<String> mTag = new LinkedList<>();
    private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public FragmentSimpleAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
        mFragmentTags = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTitles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), mInstances.get(position), null);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
            Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
            String tag = f.getTag();
            mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
        if (tag == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }

    public FragmentSimpleAdapter addFragment(String title, String tag,
                                             Class<? extends Fragment> fragment) {
        mTitles.add(title);
        mTag.add(tag);
        mInstances.add(fragment.getName());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Analytics.sendViewAnalytic(mTag.get(position))
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
}
```

Comment: post your Master Fragment.

Comment: Hi, do you solve the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

**problem:**

```
PagerSlidingTabStrip viewTabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) getActivity().findViewById(
        android.R.id.tabhost);
```

You are trying to re create and re create `PagerSlidingTabStrip` everytime you go back inside your `Master's Fragment` thus adding unnecessary fragment.

**solution:**

you need to check first if the tab already exist I dont really know about that `PagerSlidingTabStrip` I think it is a custom made class.

Comment: Removing PagerSlidingTabStrip will not fix the issue.

Comment: there seems to be a problem with ViewPager and NestedFragments, if i replace FragmentStatePagerAdapter with FragmentPagerAdapter will not leak.

Answer (score 0):

When you nest fragments inside fragments, you should instantiate the FragmentStatePagerAdapter using getChildFragmentManager and not getFragmentManager.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by moving the FragmentSimpleAdapter initialization code from onActivityCreate to onCreate